# making realtime everytime there is an insert in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, real-time

i am using ajax, in getting data from database, i already manage to display my data using ajax, and also i want to make it, if there is additional in database, it will be automatically added in my view. How can i do that, i put my code in document.ready because everytime the user clicks my page, it will automatically display all the data, but my problem is this : When the user is viewing the page, and there are additional data in database, how can i make it something realtime to add it in users view right away, when it is viewing the page. I am using codeigniter.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  show_patients();
});
function show_patients() {
  $("#queue").empty();
  $.ajax({
        url: siteurl+"myclinic/get_patients",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.length>0) {
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              $('#queue').append('<div class="col-sm-10">'+'<div class="panel-group">'+'<div class="panel panel-info">'+
                                  '<div class="panel-heading">'+'<h4><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'">'+data[i]['order_num']+' '+data[i]['patient_lname']+', '+data[i]['patient_fname']+' <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down pull-right"></span></a></h4>'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-heading -->'+'<div id="patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'+'<div class="panel-body">'+'<div class="row">'+
                                  '<div class="col-sm-4">'+'<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Check me up</button>'+'</div><!-- col-sm-4 -->'+'<div class="col-sm-6">'+
                                  '<div class="img-patient">'+'<div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url('+data[i]['patient_photo']+')"></div>'+'</div><!-- img-patient -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->'+'</div><!-- row -->'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-body -->'+'</div><!-- panel-collapse -->'+'</div><!-- panel -->'+'</div><!-- panel-group -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-10 -->');
            };
          }
          else {
            $('#queue').append('<h4> No Patients in queue </h4>');
          }
        }
  });
}
```

Comment: Realtime... perhaps read a documentation on the HTTP protocol. Request -> Send -> Done. Perhaps look into websockets to maintain an active connection.

Comment: If I understand correctly you wants to show the latest data in your view first, for that just add 'ORDER BY date field or id field' in your query. It will be not good to fetch all data at single time you should add a limit and create a pagination.@JcJohn

Comment: @parthmahida thank you for you comment sir. I want something, a listener? or maybe if there is added data in db, the view div automaticaly refresh using ajax..

Comment: @Xorifelse hello sir. thank you for your comment. i dont know how to use socket programming sir. :'(

Comment: What @parthmahida is referring to is creating a js timer to pull for updates, meaning not real time but can be quite effective depending on the server load. For websockets, there are [library's](http://socketo.me/) to make it easier.

Comment: if i go to websockets, is there alot of changes will be made ? @Xorifelse

Comment: Short answer, yes. Websockets are different than jQuery ajax requests. Not only that, there are a limited amount of open connections available. Websockets dont close connections, a request like Ajax also requires a connection but closes after the response.

Comment: is there no option that i can do @Xorifelse by using only ajax ? .. something a listener to watch everytime there was additional in DB ?

Comment: You can, make an ajax pull submitting the last ID that was updated for the client. the PHP backend can use the id to check if newer inserts exist and return a response. use jQuery to update respectively. This, within a timer, lets say update once every 60 seconds (on jQuery's end obviously)?

Comment: can i have any link or something can you add in my code posted above about 60 secs update you said ?

Comment: @Xorifelse how can i do that. Something update once every 60 seconds using Jquery.. Can you update my code above ? or any tutorial for that

Answer (score 0):

I would not run some ajax loop on a production server, aswell as if it's neccecary of the data to be fully accurate you should look into sockets, nodeJS and Socket.IO are great for this.

It will be fully real-time and it's easy to secure.

Comment: can you give me some tutorial on how to i convert this code from socket programming?.. Something infinite listener ?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the docs of nodejs with their live chat application. This should give you enough resources to adapt it to your own needs.  http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 0):

if you see for the realtime app use socke.io for nodejs thats very simple to use just you should have socket listener on your client side and a socket emmiter on your serverside that emmit an event when database has changed